# AVPlayer seekToTime does not play at correct position

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer

I have an AVPlayer which is playing a HLS video stream. My user interface provides a row of buttons, one for each "chapter" in the video (the buttons are labeled "1", "2", "3"). The app downloads some meta-data from a server which contains the list of chapter cut-in points denoted in seconds. For example, one video is 12 minutes in length - the list of chapter cut-in points are 0, 58, 71, 230, 530, etc., etc.

When the user taps one of the "chapter buttons" the button handler code does this:

```
            [self.avPlayer pause];

    [self.avPlayer seekToTime: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seekTime, 600) 
              toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero 
               toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero 
            completionHandler: ^(BOOL finished) 
            {
                [self.avPlayer play];
            }];
```

Where "seekTime" is a local var which contains the cut-in point (as described above).

The problem is that the video does not always start at the correct point. Sometimes it does. But sometimes it is anywhere from a tenth of a second, to 2 seconds BEFORE the requested seekTime. It NEVER starts after the requested seekTime.

Here are some stats on the video encoding:

Encoder: handbrakeCLI
Codec: h.264
Frame rate: 24 (actually, 23.976 - same as how it was shot)
Video Bitrate: multiple bitrates (64/150/300/500/800/1200)
Audio Bitrate: 128k
Keyframes: 23.976 (1 per second)

I am using the Apple mediafilesegmenter tool, of course, and the variantplaylistcreator to generate the playlist.

The files are being served from an Amazon Cloud/S3 bucket.

One area which I remain unclear about is CMTimeMakeWithSeconds - I have tried several variations based on different articles/docs I have read. For example, in the above excerpt I am using:

CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seekTime, 600)

I have also tried:

CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seekTime, 1)

I can't tell which is correct, though BOTH seem to produce the same inconsistent results!

I have also tried:

CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seekTime, 23.967)

Some articles claim this works like a numerator/denomenator, so n/1 should be correct where 'n' is number of seconds (as in CMTimeMakeWithseconds(n, 1)). But, the code was originally created by a different programmer (who is gone now) and he used the 600 number for the preferredTimeScale (ie. CMTimeMakeWithseconds(n, 600)).

Can anyone offer any clues as to what I am doing wrong, or even if the kind of accuracy I am trying to achieve is even possible?

And in case someone is tempted to offer "alternative" solutions, we are already considering breaking the video up into separate streams, one per chapter, but we do not believe that will give us the same performance in the sense that changing chapters will take longer as a new AVPlayerItem will have to be created and loaded, etc., etc., etc.  So if you think this is the only solution that will work (and we do expect this will achieve the result we want - ie. each chapter WILL start exactly where we want it to) feel free to say so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 95):

```
int32_t timeScale = self.player.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale;
CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(77.000000, timeScale);
[self.player seekToTime:time toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

I had a problem with 'seekToTime'. I solved my problem with this code. 'timescale' is trick for this problem.

Swift version:

```
let playerTimescale = self.player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale ?? 1
let time =  CMTime(seconds: 77.000000, preferredTimescale: playerTimescale)
self.player.seek(to: time, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero) { (finished) in /* Add your completion code here */
}
```

Comment: @jordan-bigel this should be chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: nice solution @Muhmd

Comment: Thanks, you saved me, too.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168590/seeking-accurately-as-opposed-to-two-seconds-short-in-avplayer) explains why this solution works. The emphasis is that it'll not work with `seekToTime:` but must implement zero tolerance as well.

Comment: Would `self.player.currentItem?.duration.timescale` work? Or accessing `asset` is required?

Comment: thanks saved my time. CMTime(seconds: 00.000000,  and it's started first second of videos

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion: 
1) Don't use [avplayer seekToTime: toleranceBefore: toleranceAfter: ], this will delay your seek time 4-5 seconds.

2) HLS video cut to 10 seconds per segment.  Your chapter start postion should fit the value which is multipes of 10.  As the segment starts with I frame, on this way, you can get quick seek time and accurate time.

Comment: If not using ` [avplayer seekToTime: toleranceBefore: toleranceAfter: ]` then what method should be used?

Comment: I do not agree with this. The question is "AVPlayer seekToTime does not play at correct position". By adding the toleranceBefore: toleranceAfter: parameters to seekToTime()  set to kCMTimeZero, you will solve this issue, so that is a correct answer to the question. If you don't use this, it is arbitrary where the player starts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, i solved the Lag problem with the alternate method.

Comment: i used `--segment-duration=10` option with bento4 mp4hls and does seem to have resolved it cheers

Answer (score 1):

please use function like `[player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seekTime,1)]` .
Because your tolerance value `kCMTimeZero` will take more time to seek.Instead of using tolerance value of kCMTimeZero  you can use **kCMTimeIndefinite** which is equivalent the function that i specified earlier.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: Wrong. A timescale of 1 means you can only specify whole seconds to seek to. The timescale is the number of parts per second. Use 600 for video, as Apple recommends, since it is a product of the common video frame rates like 50, 60, 25 and 24 frames per second.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code it may be resolve your problem.

```
let targetTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(videoLastDuration, 1) // videoLastDuration hold the previous video state.
self.playerController.player?.currentItem?.seekToTime(targetTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift5

```
let seconds = 45.0
let time = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 1)
player?.seek(to: time, toleranceBefore: CMTime.zero, toleranceAfter: CMTime.zero)
```