# How to seek to the last frame of AVPlayer

Tags: ios, media-player, avplayer, http-live-streaming

Is it possible to seek `AVPlayer` to the last frame of an HLS video? Whenever I seek to the time (which is equal to the current item duration), I always end up at a position a bit before the final destination. I even tried using zero before and after tolerance while seeking, but it didn't work.

How can I programmatically seek to the end of a video in `AVPlayer`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `toleranceAfter` to positive infinity.
More details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168591/7844080

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I get worse results if I set the after tolerance to positive infinity.

Comment: Did you try this one? [AVPlayer+Scrubbing.swift](https://gist.github.com/shaps80/ac16b906938ad256e1f47b52b4809512)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it helps but I faced a similar issue.

My task was to seek the last frame of a video played by `AVPlayer`.

I did that by seeking to duration value of a current item of `AVPlayer` instance. But after running the code below `AVPlayer` displayed the blank frame instead of the last frame of the video.

```
guard let duration = player?.currentItem?.asset.duration else {
  return
}
    
player?.seek(to: duration, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
```

Finally, I hopefully found the reason for the issue.

We should take into consideration that the `AVAsset` instance can contain both video and audio tracks (usually it is a single video track and a single audio track) and there could be a case when the duration of the audio track is larger than the duration of the video track.
So we should get the duration of the video track (`AVAssetTrack` instance has an appropriate property `timeRange`) of `AVAsset` and use it to seek the last frame of `AVPlayer`.
The code below solved my issue.

```
guard let firstVideoTrack = player?.currentItem?.asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
  return
}
    
let duration = firstVideoTrack.timeRange.duration
    
player?.seek(to: duration, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
```

There could be more complex cases when an audio track starts before a video track or there are several video and/ or audio tracks inside a single asset. In this case, please check `start` property of `timeRange` struct of `AVAssetTrack` and perform appropriate actions.

Please also keep in mind that some `AVAsset` fields (for instance, `tracks`) are loaded asynchronously. Ensure you used `loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys:completionHandler:)` method of `AVAsset` to load them before reading.